# render show page inside index page, how to put a different id on each modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, modal-dialog, partial

I am using a Modal to pop up the show page inside the index page.....Everything works just fine until I click on a product. For some reason, the same name is popping up for every product on the modal

I know it's an easy fix, please help....new to rails 
This is my code:

**Views**

_show.html.erb

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="content-inner hero-unit">
    <h1 class="pump-up center">
      <br>
      <strong>Coming Soon.</strong></h1>
      <br><br>
      <p>
        <b>Name: </b>
        **<%= @product.name %>**
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="span3">

      <%= render :partial => 'products/show', :locals => { :product => product }  %>
        <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
        <%=(image_tag product.photo(:medium))%></a>

      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Model**

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :photo
end
```

**Controller**

products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end


  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok The issue is with this code.

In Index.html.erb

It should be

```
<a href="#myModal<%=product.id %>" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
```

And Change ur _show.html.erb to this

```
<div id="myModal<%=product.id%>" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

This should do the JOB.

Also I see that you are not using the local variable that is passed from index action. you are using @product which may be an issue, try using just 'product' that is being passed from the index.html.erb

Comment: so would the code look like this for the index?                      <a href="#myModal[1,2,3,4]" role="button" data-toggle="modal">

and what if i have over 100 products.....would i have to list them all? @Abibullah Rahamathulah

Comment: href=#mymodel_1, and the same id should be present in the show.html.haml for id=1

Comment: i think i am having a similar problem here......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561659/like-button-and-ajax   can you please lend a hand @Abibullah Rahamathulah